# Sumif in Postgresql between two tables

Tags: postgresql, sumifs

These are my two sample tables.

table "outage" (column formats are text, timestamp, timestamp)

```
+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
| outage_request_id |  actual_start  |   actual_end   |
+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1-07697685        | 4/8/2015 4:48  | 4/8/2015 9:02  |
| 1-07223444        | 7/17/2015 4:24 | 8/01/2015 9:23 |
| 1-07223450        | 2/13/2015 4:24 | 4/29/2015 1:03 |
| 1-07223669        | 4/28/2017 9:20 | 4/30/2017 6:58 |
| 1-08985319        | 8/24/2015 3:18 | 8/24/2015 8:27 |
+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

and a second table "prices" (column format is numeric, timestamp)

```
+-------+---------------+
| price |     stamp     |
+-------+---------------+
| -2.31 | 2/1/2018 3:00 |
| -2.35 | 2/1/2018 4:00 |
| -1.77 | 2/1/2018 5:00 |
| -2.96 | 2/1/2018 6:00 |
| -5.14 | 2/1/2018 7:00 |
+-------+---------------+
```

My Goal: To sum the prices in between the start and stop times of each outage_request_id.

I have no idea how to go about properly joining the tables and getting a sum of prices in those outage timestamp ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't promise this is efficient (in fact for very large tables I feel pretty confident it's not), but this should notionally get you what you want:

```
select
  o.outage_request_id, o.actual_start, o.actual_end,
  sum (p.price) as total_price
from
  outage o
  left join prices p on
    p.stamp between o.actual_start and o.actual_end
 group by
   o.outage_request_id, o.actual_start, o.actual_end
```

Comment: hmm. I'm getting a null price sum. One wrinkle is that the outage table is timestamp WITH timezone while the prices table is timestamp WITHOUT timezone. Should that matter for the join? The times are actually correct. So my timestamp in table "outage" looks like 2015-04-08 04:48:00-04. And my timestamp in "prices" looks like 2018-01-01 01:00:00

Comment: the format difference being the "-04" on the end of the outage table timestamps.

Comment: it looks like the outage table has timestamps with time zones and the prices table has it without time zones.  I'm actually not sure how the equality relationships work in this case, but I'm PostgreSQL has a pretty good track record of getting it right in cases like this.  Do you know why the different datatypes, and can you harmonize them?

Comment: Ah ha! My actual code incorrectly had a timestamp WHERE clause in the price table that didn't span any of the outage times. Just had to remove that. Your code works great. Thanks.